# Strapi populate all fields with custom slug id field query

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have followed this official tutorial for replacing the Strapi ID field with a "slug" field, so that I can query by name or another unique id: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVV0CfgX6Qk

However now my query `api/partners/my_partners?populate=*` doesn't populate all the fields like before.

How can I change that?
That's my current code:

controller

```
module.exports = createCoreController('api::partner.partner', ({strapi}) => ({
    async findOne(context) {
        const partner_id = context.params.id
        const populate = context.params.query

        const entity = await strapi.db.query('api::partner.partner').findOne({
            where: { partner_id }
        })

        const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity)

        return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity)
    }
}));
```

routes

```
module.exports = {
    routes: [
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/partners/:partner_id',
            handler: 'partner.findOne',
            config: {
                auth: false,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```